# Error when changing api lifecycle state to Publish in wso2 api manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, lifecycle

I faced with following exception in wso2 api manager 3.2.0,  when changing api lifecycle state to Publish. When I want to change state to publish, I faced error and after repeating and clicking more than two times it changed state and also throw following exception:

```
Error while updating the API in Gateway 7c395ffc-ad21-4a56-8dc1-e0cd459fa266




 ERROR - GovernanceArtifactImpl Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed. Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while Deploying API "},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
    org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while Deploying API "},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
```

Error while updating the API in Gateway 7c395ffc-ad21-4a56-8dc1-e0cd459fa266

Could please guide me to solve following problem

Complete log :

```
  nsumer#tokenRevocation
[2021-09-22 10:40:16,352]  WARN - OAuth2AuthzEndpoint No session state found for the received Session ID : e39a2551-0b03-4cdc-828f-245597734
[2021-09-22 10:41:54,194]  INFO - DataBridge user admin connected
[2021-09-22 10:41:54,377]  INFO - JMSConnectionFactory JMS ConnectionFactory : notificationJMSPublisher initialized
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,134]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2021-09-22 10:41:57,134+0330]
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,264]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : 0a1f10b7-87e8-4bb2-b680-b64762218445 was added to the Synapse configtion successfully
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,274]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : x1--v1.0.0_APIproductionEndpoint was added to the Synapse configurationccessfully
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,279]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : x1--v1.0.0_APIsandboxEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration sussfully
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,322] ERROR - SynapseConfiguration URL context: /shaparak/1.0.0 is already registered with the API: admin--serviceager:v1.0.0
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,323]  INFO - API {api:admin--x1:v1.0.0} Destroying API: admin--x1:v1.0.0
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,324]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler Unable to destroy uninitialized authentication handler instance
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,324] ERROR - SynapseConfiguration No API exists by the name: admin--x1:v1.0.0
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,343] ERROR - APIGatewayManager Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while Deploying API
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.deployAPI_aroundBody14(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:215) ~[org.wso2.con.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.deployAPI(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:210) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.l_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishAPIToGatewayEnvironment_aroundBody4(APIGatewayManager.java:214) [org.w.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishAPIToGatewayEnvironment(APIGatewayManager.java:192) [org.wso2.carbon.agt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishToGateway_aroundBody2(APIGatewayManager.java:144) [org.wso2.carbon.api.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishToGateway(APIGatewayManager.java:118) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.76.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.publishToGateway_aroundBody116(APIProviderImpl.java:2438) [org.wso2.carbon.apimimpl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.publishToGateway(APIProviderImpl.java:2410) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.20ar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways_aroundBody100(APIProviderImpl.java:2168) [owso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(APIProviderImpl.java:2134) [org.wso2.carbonimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways_aroundBody28(UserAwareAPIProvider.java4) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:191) [org.wscarbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.changeLifeCycle_aroundBody4(APIExecutor.java:190) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgtpl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.changeLifeCycle(APIExecutor.java:158) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.20ar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute_aroundBody2(APIExecutor.java:132) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.06.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:93) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712) [.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450) [org.wso2.carbon.ernance.registry.extensions_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java6) [org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2794) [org.wso2.carbon.registryre_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518) [org.wsoarbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2607) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510) [org.wso2.carbon.regis.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1964) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.ar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829) [orgo2.carbon.governance.api_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808) [orgo2.carbon.governance.api_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus_aroundBody272(APIProviderImpl.java:5697) [org.wso2.carbonimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:5620) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus_aroundBody74(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:358) [org.wsoarbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:354) [org.wso2.carbon.apimimpl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisChangeLifecyclePost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:3932) asses/:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.apisChangeLifecyclePost(ApisApi.java:875) [classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:38]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.ar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3..jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3..jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar2.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.ja.2.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86) [org.wsoarbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authzlve_1.4.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:101) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authlve_1.4.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.e4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145) [org.wsoarbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcext_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119) [org.wso2.carbon.tom.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_291]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_291]
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while publishing API to the Gateway. No API exists by the name: admin--x1:v1.0.0
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:382) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:457) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.stub.APIGatewayAdminStub.deployAPI(APIGatewayAdminStub.java:4705) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gway.stub_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.deployAPI_aroundBody14(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:213) ~[org.wso2.con.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        ... 83 more
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,476]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2021-09-22 10:41:57,476+0330]
[2021-09-22 10:41:58,114]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2021-09-22 10:41:58,114+0330]
[2021-09-22 10:41:58,443] ERROR - APIExecutor Failed to publish service gateway while executing APIExecutor.
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.FaultGatewaysException: null
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPIforStateChange_aroundBody104(APIProviderImpl.java:2292) ~[org.wso2.car.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPIforStateChange(APIProviderImpl.java:2199) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.imp.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPIforStateChange_aroundBody32(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:207) ~[org.2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPIforStateChange(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:204) ~[org.wso2.carbon.agt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.changeLifeCycle_aroundBody4(APIExecutor.java:200) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgmpl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.changeLifeCycle(APIExecutor.java:158) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.2jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute_aroundBody2(APIExecutor.java:132) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.06.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:93) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712) [.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450) [org.wso2.carbon.ernance.registry.extensions_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java6) [org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2794) [org.wso2.carbon.registryre_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518) [org.wsoarbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2607) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510) [org.wso2.carbon.regis.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1964) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.ar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829) [orgo2.carbon.governance.api_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808) [orgo2.carbon.governance.api_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus_aroundBody272(APIProviderImpl.java:5697) [org.wso2.carbonimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:5620) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus_aroundBody74(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:358) [org.wsoarbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:354) [org.wso2.carbon.apimimpl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisChangeLifecyclePost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:3932) asses/:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.apisChangeLifecyclePost(ApisApi.java:875) [classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:38]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.ar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3..jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3..jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar2.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.ja.2.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86) [org.wsoarbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authzlve_1.4.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:101) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authlve_1.4.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.e4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145) [org.wsoarbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcext_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119) [org.wso2.carbon.tom.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_291]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_291]
[2021-09-22 10:41:58,449] ERROR - DefaultLifeCycle org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for acn : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while Deploying API "},"UNPUBLISHED"}
[2021-09-22 10:41:58,473] ERROR - GovernanceArtifactImpl Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed. Execution failed for action : Pubh Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while Deploying API "},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysExcept:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while Deploying API "},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:482) ~[org.wso2.carbonvernance.registry.extensions_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java6) ~[org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2794) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registrore_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518) ~[org.wscarbon.registry.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2607) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.cor.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510) ~[org.wso2.carbon.regiy.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1964) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829) [orgo2.carbon.governance.api_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808) [orgo2.carbon.governance.api_4.8.19.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus_aroundBody272(APIProviderImpl.java:5697) [org.wso2.carbonimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:5620) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6206.jar:?]
```

Comment: Is this an all-in-one setup or a distributed setup where the publisher and gateway are in separate nodes?

Comment: Can you post the complete error trace?

Comment: It is all in one setup

Comment: Is it failing continuously? Can you add the complete error stack here?

Comment: I updated question. When I want to change state to publish, I faced error and after repeating and clicking more than two times it changed state and also throw following exception : Error while updating the API in Gateway

Comment: I updated Log ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the logs it seems that this issue is occurring only for one particular API. In the shared carbon log file, the following line indicates that the **admin--x1:v1.0.0** API has been deleted.

```
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,323]  INFO - API {api:admin--x1:v1.0.0} Destroying API: admin--x1:v1.0.0
```

In the next lines you can observe the error message mentioning that the API you are trying to publish doesn't exists.

```
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,324] ERROR - SynapseConfiguration No API exists by the name: admin--x1:v1.0.0
[2021-09-22 10:41:57,343] ERROR - APIGatewayManager Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while Deploying API
```

The possible reason could be that either the API **admin--x1:v1.0.0** has been deleted completely from the system or it has been deleted partially and still getting displayed in the publisher portal. If its partially deleted, then you can completely delete the API from all its referenced locations and create a new API. Then you can try to publish that API.  You can refer https://m-saranki.medium.com/right-the-wrong-get-rid-of-partially-deleted-apis-in-wso2-apim-29c2bdd564e4 to completely remove the partially deleted APIs. The blog is shown for APIM-2.X.X but its applicable for APIM-3.2.0 as well.

Comment: So, It is not possible to define api with same context?

Comment: The API context is used by the Gateway to identify the API. Therefore, the API context must be unique. This context is the API's root context when invoking the API through the Gateway.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Saranki Magenthirarajah

Comment: Anytime @Tohid Makari!